# Spring @Scheduled fixedRate giving odd results?

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I need to run a task in a periodic manner, so I looked up the `@Scheduled` annotation.

I used the following code:

```
public class MyTask {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000L)
    public void testScheduling() {
        System.out.println("Run Me ~ " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
Run Me ~ 1419859820512
Run Me ~ 1419859821671
Run Me ~ 1419859822512
Run Me ~ 1419859823670
Run Me ~ 1419859824512
Run Me ~ 1419859825671
Run Me ~ 1419859826513
Run Me ~ 1419859827670
Run Me ~ 1419859828513
Run Me ~ 1419859829671
Run Me ~ 1419859830513
```

I don't understand why it's about 1100 miliseconds and 900 miliseconds rather than 2000 miliseconds. What can I do to fix this other than just multiplying it by two? This is oddly unpredictable.

EDIT: The commenters are right:

```
System.out.println("Run Me (" + this.hashCode() + ") ~ " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Gives me

```
Run Me (1315556362) ~ 1419863164220
Run Me (410352054) ~ 1419863164540
Run Me (1315556362) ~ 1419863166221
Run Me (410352054) ~ 1419863166540
```

So I'll have to figure out why there are two instances of the bean.

EDIT: For some reason, there are two web app initializers, one being a webappinitializer, the other being a security initializer

```
public class BackendWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    ....
}
```

and

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(WebSecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

For some reason, as a result of these two initializers, two instances are initiated. Not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't believe Java exposes a high-precision scheduling method -- likely Spring is just delegating to some `ScheduledExecutorService` using `scheduleWithFixedRate`, which does not guarantee millisecond precision.

Comment: @TomG there's a difference between "not guaranteeing milisecond precision" and running the task twice as often as it should.

Comment: Are you creating two beans?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I only defined the bean once in the XML, removed that and added `@Component` annotation because otherwise it wasn't working, but you're right, it probably instantiates two of the bean. I'm not sure why...

Comment: Let's your context configuration and how you load it.

Comment: If it is once in xml make sure you aren't loading it twice or that you aren't scanning for the same components twice (can happen if you have both a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` scanning the same packages). Add the `hashCode` of the bean to your `System.out` call that way you can determine if it is a single instance or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum smart call on the `hashCode()`, you're right, it's two instances - although this is some really awkward hidden error. I'll try to look into what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the cause of the double instantiation problem. It was the following.

We had the following two main configurations:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(WebSecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ ... })
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource({ "classpath:spring-config.xml" })
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

But apparently, this setup instantiates the Application Context **twice**. The solution is the following:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        //super(WebSecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ ... })
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource({ "classpath:spring-config.xml" })
@Import({WebSecurityConfig.class})
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

Comment: please note that this gave an error regarding a missing `ContextLoaderListener` so I'm looking for the cause of that.